# Recuperar lista escrita em arquivo com Python

Tags: python, lista

Gostava de ir ao meu ficheiro que contem o seguinte

```
['teste1', '27-12-18', '12/5/2015', 'Aberta']
['teste2', '27-12-18', '6/7/7', 'Aberta']
['teste3', '27-12-18', '12/5/6', 'Fechada']
```

e apenas mostrar se o 3 campo estiver Aberto tenho o seguinte código;

Escrita no arquivo:

```
def annexsentence():

    data_inicio=input("Nome da Tarefa :")

    data_final=input("Data Final :") #placeholder ano-mes-dia

    data_atual = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y")

    estado="Aberta"

    lista=[data_inicio,str(data_atual),str(data_final),estado]

    annexsentence=open("ficheiro.txt","a")

    annexsentence.write(str(lista)+"\n")

    annexsentence.close()

annexsentence()
```

Leitura do arquivo:

```
def mostrar():
    #ler linha a linha
    with open("ficheiro.txt") as arquivo:
        for linha in arquivo:
            if linha[3]=="Aberta":
                print (linha)
            else:
                print("ola")
mostrar()
```

Alguém me consegue explicar o que devo fazer para corrigir?

Se fizer `print(linha[3])` retorna e de teste e se meter `linha[0]` aparece `[`

Comment: Você que gerou o arquivo?

Comment: sim, eu tenho mais codigo mas acho que o problema é aqui

Comment: A questão é de como o Python irá interpretar o conteúdo do arquivo. Da maneira que escreveu o arquivo não uma forma tão trivial de recuperar a estrutura, então provavelmente a solução ideal seja refazer a lógica de escrita do arquivo. Você pode utilizar JSON ou serializar o objeto, por exemplo.

Comment: mas neste caso tenho mesmo de usar python é para um projeto do curso, mas o que me esta a fazer confusão e só estar aparecer 1 carácter e não tudo

Comment: A sugestão é ainda continuar usando Python, mas escrevendo o arquivo de uma maneira que seja mais simples recuperar os dados. Por favor, edite a pergunta e adicione o código que utiliza para escrever no arquivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como comentado, a forma que utilizou para escrever no arquivo não é a ideal para recuperar os dados posteriormente. Você apenas converteu a lista em uma *string* antes de escrever no arquivo, mas esse processo não é trivialmente reversível, podendo gerar inúmeros efeitos colaterais.

```
annexsentence.write(str(lista)+"\n")
```

A melhor forma de fazer isso é utilizando algum formato que seja reversível. Você pode, por exemplo, utilizar o formato JSON:

```
import json

annexsentence.write(json.dumps(lista) + "\n")
```

E durante a leitura, recuperar os dados com `dados = json.loads(linha)`. Desta forma, `dados` será novamente uma lista com os valores que deseja.

Outra forma é serializar o seu objeto. Uma das formas de se fazer isso é com o pacote [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), onde, na escrita, você faz:

```
import pickle

annexsentence.write(pickle.dumps(lista) + "\n")
```

Enquanto na leitura, para recuperar os dados, você pode fazer `dados = pickle.loads(linha)`. Novamente `dados` será uma lista com os valores desejados.

Estude as soluções e veja qual é mais adequada às suas necessidades.

Comment: muito obrigado vou experimentar

Answer (score -1):

[TL;DL](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/use-split?language=python3)
Use `re.sub()`, e `split()`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import re

ln = "['teste1', '27-12-18', '12/5/2015', 'Aberta']"

# Removendo os caracteres indesejados
ln = re.sub("\[|\]|'","",ln)

# Convertendo a string em uma lista
lst = ln.split(', ')

print(lst[3])
Aberta
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/use-split?language=python3)

> Adaptando à sua função de leitura do arquivo:

```
def mostrar():
    #ler linha a linha
    with open("ficheiro.txt") as arquivo:
        for linha in arquivo:
            ln = linha.strip()
            ln = re.sub("\[|\]|'","",ln)
            lst = ln.split(', ')
            if lst[3]=="Aberta":
                print (linha)
            else:
                print("ola")
mostrar()
['teste1', '27-12-18', '12/5/2015', 'Aberta']

['teste2', '27-12-18', '6/7/7', 'Aberta']

ola
```

**Obs.**
Se voce pode alterar a forma de gerar o arquivo, sugiro que armazene cada linha com os valores apenas separados por vírgulas, assim:

```
teste1,27-12-18,12/5/2015,Aberta
teste2,27-12-18,6/7/7,Aberta
teste3,27-12-18,12/5/6,Fechada
```

Dessa forma vc não precisaria usar `re` e sua função de leitura deveria ser alterada para uma forma mais simples:

```
def mostrar():
    #ler linha a linha
    with open("ficheiro.txt") as arquivo:
        for linha in arquivo:
            ln = linha.strip()
            lst = ln.split(',')
            if lst[3]=="Aberta":
                print (linha)
            else:
                print("ola")
```