# Como encontrar as listas que possuem um certo item desejado

Tags: python, lista, arquivo

Gostaria de verificar se um item específico de uma lista é igual a `"Aberta"`.

```py
def mostrar():
    with open("ficheiro2.txt") as arquivo:
        i=0
        for linha in arquivo:
            linha = eval(linha)
            if linha[i][2]=="Aberta":
                i=i+1
                print (linha)

mostrar()
```

O ficheiro contém o seguinte conteúdo:

```
[['teste', '02-01-19', 'Aberta'],['teste2', '02-01-19', 'Aberta'],['teste3', '02-01-19', 'Fechada']]
```

E eu queria verificar se o item de índice 2 da lista que está dentro de outra lista, é igual a `"Aberta"`. Assim, ele deve mostrar todas as listas em que esse item é igual a esse valor.

A saída que obtive até agora foi essa:

```
[['pedrito', '02-01-19', 'Aberta'], ['pedrito', '02-01-19', 'Aberta'], ['pedrito', '02-01-19', 'Fechada']]
```

Mas eu gostaria que fosse essa:

```
[['pedrito', '02-01-19', 'Aberta'], ['pedrito', '02-01-19', 'Aberta']]
```

Comment: Bem como comentei na [sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353302/5878), essa não é a melhor forma de resolver o problema. Por que armazenou as informações desta forma e utilizou o `eval`? As alternativas dadas não resolveram o problema? Por que não?

Comment: Para perceber o erro do seu código, recomendo que faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878).

Comment: Esta pergunta ja foi respondida, uma das respostas [é essa aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353323/7412)

Comment: Não use o `eval()` se a pessoa o enviar um arquivo com essas linhas `fm = windll.LoadLibrary('fmifs.dll')` e `fm.FormatEx(c_wchar_p(Drive), 0x0C, c_wchar_p(Format),  c_wchar_p(Title), True, c_int(0), WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, c_void_p)(NULL))` você terá o HD apagado.

Answer (score 3):

Você está obtendo um resultado diferente, pois o algoritmo que você está utilizando não faz o que você está querendo.

No código, você verifica se o elemento de índice 2, da *sublista* na posição `i`, é igual a `"Aberta"`.

```py
if linha[i][2]=="Aberta":
```

No entanto, se isso é "verdade", ao invés de imprimir somente as *sublistas* que estão "abertas", você imprime todas as *sublistas*, inclusive as que estão "fechadas".

```py
linha = eval(linha)
if linha[i][2]=="Aberta":
    i=i+1
    # aqui
    print (linha)
```

Além disso, conforme o @Woss comentou (e respondeu na outra pergunta), ao invés de usar o `eval`, você poderia utilizar a [função `json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), para obter as listas, ou *sublistas*, contidas no arquivo.

---

Por fim, não é necessário esse código todo. Você pode simplificá-lo, deixando dessa forma:

```py
def mostrar(): 
    with open("ficheiro2.txt") as arquivo:
         lista = json.load(arquivo)
         print([sublista for sublista in lista if sublista[2] == "Aberta"]) 

mostrar()
```

Ou seja:

- Usamos a [estrutura `with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/125486) para lidar com a abertura e o fechamento do arquivo que queremos;
- Obtemos a lista contida no arquivo através da [função `json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) (que lida diretamente com esses objetos de arquivo);
- E, para cada *sublista* que existir, armazenamos, [em uma nova lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), aquelas que possuírem o valor `"Aberta"` na posição 2.

Por fim, mostramos essa nova lista através da função `print`.

Espero ter ajudado!